# correcting the Indents on my Fascia boards --- after I chipped and sanded the old paint and then primed and painted

Tags: painting

I  spent a lot of time chipping , scraping , sanding the fascia boards    some of the paint would not come off  and my circular sander just does not do the job my old belt sander did .  Anyway, I put on two prime coats and two topcoats , but the indents are still visible. The man at the paint store said I should have put some mud on in the beginning and use a wide trowel to smooth it out.

Any help from the audience out there ?

Comment: What's the question, exactly? You got some good advice. Where are you confused?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to scuff up the paint in the area(s) that need attention, then use *exterior spackle* with a broad knife (as the astute salesman pointed out).

Then sand smooth and **re**-prime and **re**-paint.

Comment: OK  Jimmy  Fix-it   I  will use the exterior spackle process on one fascia board  on the west side of my building which is the only board that looks  indented  .   I  will let  you and our audience know what happens . Thanks  for  your  comments   Bob

Answer (score 0):

Chisel clean the area and then use an autobody filler like Bondo with a putty knife.